# Css fixed box positioning issue

Tags: css, css-position

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="fixed-top-bar" style="position:fixed"></div>
        <div class="content" style="position:static"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my browser, both div starts from top left of the browser.

In firebug, I set both div with "display: block" so each div element should take a row of space.
Why do I see them stacked on the top left? How can I make it look normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When applying `position: fixed`, the element gets pulled out of the natural flow of the page. This causes all other elements to ignore that elements position. That's why the static `div` lies below the fixed `div`.

The fixed `div`'s position relates to the parent element which in this case is `body`. Since you didn't give it any `left` `top` `right` `bottom` position data, it just behaves like `top: 0; left: 0;` which happens to be the exact same postion where your static `div` lies below.

To resolve this, I'd simply add the same amount of `padding-top` to the `body` as the fixed `div` is high.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

By the way, a `div` naturally behaves as if you'd give it `display: block`. In fact, that's its only default styling.

Answer (score 1):

For "`position: fixed`": The element is positioned relative to the browser window.
This is overriding your `display: block` setting for the div. So if you can, change positioning from `fixed` to some other value and it'll obey other elements rules.